# How to implement image dynamically in multiple views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a way to display the Image dynamically based on `Placement_Position` and `Region` into different View.

`Placement` view, where I display all the content from table.

There is no link between these Views.

I am confused, how to implement this scenario. Anyone please help me here.

In `Employee` view, I want to display  the image `Atop_1`if the region is `1` and `Atop_2` if the region is `2`

[image: Table]

```
   public class ClsPlacement
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Placement_Position { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public int Region { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller

```
       public ActionResult Placement()
        {
            var model = context.Placement.ToList();
            return View(model);
        }
```

Placement View

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Id)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Placement_Position)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Region)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Path)
        </th>


    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Placement_Position)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Region)
            </td>
            <td>
               @Html.Image(item.Path, "Image")
            </td>

        </tr>
                    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **LINQ** to write query for each controller and return `IList` :

so in **Employee** view :

```
    public ActionResult Employee()
    {
     IList<ClsPlacement> plcList = new List<ClsPlacement>();
     var query= from m in context.Placement
                select m;
     var plc= query.ToList();
        foreach(var plcData in plc)
        {
         if(plcData.Placement_Position=="A_Top")
          {
           plcList.Add(new ClsPlacement()
            {
                Id= plcData.Id,
                Placement_Position= plcData.Placement_Position,
                Path = plcData.Path ,
                Region= plcData.Region
            });
          }
        }
        return View(plcList);      
    }
```

then in your view you can write this:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
{
     <div class="col-md-5">  
     <img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Content/Place/{0}{1}{2}", "Atop_",item.Region,".jpg"))" />
</div>
}
```

and same this for **Customer** view.

Comment: But there is small problem. In Employee Controller, they are returning their own model so how can I return `plcList` in the same view. Thank you.

Comment: Please help me. I have two model where one for employee and another for Placement. Here, you have used 2nd one and returned the view. But, it is actually its own View. I am lost how to return this data inside Employee View.

Comment: It returns model from `ClsEmployee model = new ClsEmployee();`. ` return View(model);`.

Comment: @mvc you still can join them with linq query if they have foreign-key

Comment: something like this :  var query = (from b in context.BuyFactors
                     join d in context.BuyFactorDetail
                     on
..
                     select new
                     {
                        BuyFactorId = b.BuyFactorId,
                        ....
                        BuyFactorDetailId = d.BuyFactorDetailId,
                        ...
    ..
                 }));

Comment: can you please invite me for chat if possible then.

Comment: i still don't have enough reputation to create chat rooms ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174917/discussion-between-mohammad-and-mvc).

Comment: `<img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Content/Place/{0}{1}", "Atop_",item.Region))" />` is not working and also please show me how to include extension dynamically.